# warning: improper pointer/integer combination: op "="

Tags: c, gcc-warning, solaris-10

I compile a C program in Solaris and get this warning.

```
line 68: warning: improper pointer/integer combination: op "="
```

My code contains

```
struct cmsghdr  *cmsg;
```

Line 68 is

```
cmsg = CMSG_FIRSTHDR(&msg);
```

The structure cmsghdr and CMSG_FIRSTHDR is defined in socket.h as

```
#define  CMSG_FIRSTHDR(m)
--
--

struct cmsghdr {
        socklen_t       cmsg_len;  
        int             cmsg_level;
        int             cmsg_type; 
};
```

I have included socket.h in my code. But still I get this error.

Comment: Could you check if `SOL_SOCKET` is a pointer, maybe?

Comment: line 68 is "cmsg = CMSG_FIRSTHDR(&msg);"

Comment: Then you'll need to tell us what the CMSG_FIRSTHDR macro looks like.

Comment: What is the declaration of `msg`?

Comment: This is how it is declared. struct msghdr   msg; msghdr is also defined in socket.h.

Comment: `#define CMSG_FIRSTHDR(m)` is not the complete definition of CMSG_FIRSTHDR, is it?

Comment: socket.h contains this line only. socket.h is an OS header...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the `CMSG_FIRSTHDR` macro doesn't do proper typecasting, so you have to do it yourself:

```
cmsg = (struct msghdr *) (CMSG_FIRSTHDR(&msg));
```

It might also be that there is some improper casting inside the macro itself, in which case there is nothing you can do, as it's in a system header.

Answer (score -1):

please check what type  SOL_SOCKET is. It needs to be int.
Change the type of the filed "cmsg_level" in your struct, if it dosen't match.

I guess SOL_SOCKET is a pointer, maybe   int*

Comment: in socket.h, SOL_SOCKET is defined as "#define  SOL_SOCKET      0xffff          /* options for socket level */"

Comment: The warning you get usually means that you don't included every neccessary header file properly. I don't have any other idea - sorry

Comment: As much as I analysed, "cmsghdr" is defined only in socket.h and it is not present in any other header file.

Comment: EDIT: are you sure, that the problem is that line?

Comment: Hi Tectu, I have edited the question to include the previous line too. "CMSG_FIRSTHDR" is also defined in socket.h

Comment: I don't know CMSG or whatever you are using, but try this:
cmsg = *CMSG_FIRSTHDR(&msg);    or   cmsg = CMSG_FIRSTHDR(msg);

Comment: please learn the difference between errors and warnings - your posts are very missleading

Comment: "cmsg = CMSG_FIRSTHDR(msg)" gives the same warning. "*CMSG_FIRSTHDR(&msg)" gives the warning "cannot dereference non-pointer type".